# How can I use SVM in OpenCV with 2 channel Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I want to classify coordinate set using SVM in OpenCV. 
For example,
label 1 for { 70, 80 }, { 94, 90 }, { 70, 85 }
label -1 for { 98, 89 },{ 99, 94 }, { 91, 87 }

In the example offered by OpenCV, only one coordinate data is
used for one node. However, I want to use coordinate set as 
one node. I tried this using CV_32FC2 Mat for test. 
However, I think it can not be used for training of SVM. Error happened. 
Somebody know how to use SVM for this case?

```
int record[3][3][2] = {
    {
        { 70, 80 }, 
        { 94, 90 },
        { 70, 85 }  
    },
    {
        { 83, 90 }, 
        { 95, 60 }, 
        { 90, 82 }  
    },
    {
        { 98, 89 }, // 3반 학생1의 성적
        { 99, 94 }, // 3반 학생2의 성적
        { 91, 87 }  // 3반 학생3의 성적
    }
};

int labels[3] = { 1, -1, -1 };
Mat trainingDataMat(3, 3, CV_32FC2, record);
Mat labelsMat(3, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);


Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));
//! [init]
//! [train]
svm->train(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you choose size of trainingDataMat to be 3x3?

Have a look at this tutorial code, which uses 2D points as training data.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

As you can see, they use only 2 colums:

```
// Set up training data
float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

float trainingData[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };
Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
```

If you want to use integers instead of floats, you'll have to adjust types.

Comment: I already understood the tutorial code you said. It consider only position of node through x, y coordinate. However I want to consider the relation between points. It's like finding specific figure among various figures. So I need to use set of coordinates as a object.

Comment: similar to bag of words? Sorry, no experience there, I guess the number of rows will have to be a multiple of 2 then?

Comment: cols,.I meant the number of cols should be a multiple of 2 and the number of features per object must be fixed?

Comment: I solved problem. you were right. I misunderstood about dimension. Thank you for your comment.